# is there any better approach then K folds and nested K fold

Tags: python, cross-validation

I am trying to understand what problem is K-folds solving. It does not seem to be solving data leakage at all, as we are still testing on test data and then taking an average of all test folds and then retune the model.

I can understand that with each model, it is like training on new data set, this seems to be the positive point.

Now, if I understand correctly, nested K folds seems to be solving this data leakage problem. but it is like performing the model tuning K times and coming up with K models. I really dont see much benefit rather then having 5 model and using them on real time.

Now, why cant simply we have alternative approach. Have K folds, keep 1 fold as only test data. Use K-1 folds for K fold validation (K-2 for train, 1 fold for CV). Using this way, we evaluate our model on unseen data.

But certainly, there must be some drawbacks with this, I want to understand why this alternative approach is better then K folds and nested K fold.

Comment: Your suggestion seems to be 2-fold nested cross-validation. For a given apriori fixed algorithm, K-fold cross-validation gives you fair estimates of its performance. You fit it K times on K datasets and evaluate it K times on K independent unseen validation sets and then average. There is no data leakage in this case. If your estimator itself uses internal cross-validation (e.g. LASSO or CV-tuned xgboost) then this still works. You apply K-fold cross-validation to this estimator, which leads to nested cross-validation.